# Rtmp streaming to h.264

Tags: android, streaming, rtmp

I'm trying to use a rtmp stream to stream a live channel through an android app to enjoy the live channel. When using the rtmp stream in the app it is showing an error. This is my rtmp stream

```
rtmp://cp86438.live.edgefcs.net/live/livestream6_68@24590 
Channel ZNS( Local channel in the bahamas) grab the stream using url snooper
```

I'm trying to add this to a channel listing.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Please, you should always include clear information about what you have done sofar and the error you are getting so you can receive relevant help.